# How to select only first rows that satisfies conditions in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

I want to select only the first row from start that match my MonetDB query and to give it as output and ignoring the rest. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the SQL LIMIT clause for this, e.g.

SELECT * FROM yourtable LIMIT 1;